# How do I supply configuration to elastic beanstalk tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

when deploying locally to tomcat, I make this change (below) to server.xml, is there a way I can supply this to Elastic Beanstalk?

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" 
       protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
       redirectPort="8443"/>'
```

thanks
'

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do it now without providing custom AMI. Follow instructions in: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/10/customize-elastic-beanstalk-using-configuration-files.html

In order to provide custom server xml create .ebextensions folder in webapp, put there custom **server.xml** file and add one more file: **server-update.config** with content:

```
container_commands:
  replace-config:
  command: cp .ebextensions/server.xml /etc/tomcat7/server.xml
```

Comment: Hello, i tried to do it this way and I got the following error message: "The configuration file .ebextensions/server-update.config in application version gd377807-dirty contains invalid YAML or JSON. YAML exception: while scanning for the next token found character '\t' that cannot start any token in "<reader>", line 2, column 3: replace-config: ^ , JSON exception: Unexpected character (c) at position 0.. Update the configuration file.

Comment: This is because YAML does not support TAB (\t) characters at the start of the line, you must use only spaces

Comment: @sebsto, Wow.  I wish I more than one "Plus One" to give.

Comment: @Maciej Walkowiak I am getting error message that replace-config failed. I had created .ebextensions in web-inf folder and added two files server.xml and server-update.config. When I check logs i can find that cannot read file at .ebextensions/server.xml what might be the problem

Comment: @MaciejWalkowiak  How would I add muliple commands to the server-update.config file?

Comment: The easiest way would be just combine them with &&.

Comment: You could also call a bash script located in your .ebextensions folder

Answer (score 19):

Another way to implement this without replacing the entire Tomcat `server.xml` file is using the following in your `.ebextensions` folder (e.g. `tomcat.config`)

```
files:
  "/tmp/update_tomcat_server_xml.sh":
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: "000755"
    content: |
      #! /bin/bash
      CONFIGURED=`grep -c '<Connector port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8"' /etc/tomcat7/server.xml`
      if [ $CONFIGURED = 0 ]
        then
          sed -i 's/Connector port="8080"/Connector port="8080" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/' /etc/tomcat7/server.xml
          logger -t tomcat_conf "/etc/tomcat7/server.xml updated successfully"
          exit 0
        else
          logger -t tomcat_conf "/etc/tomcat7/server.xml already updated"
          exit 0
      fi

container_commands:
  00_update_tomcat_server_xml:
    command: sh /tmp/update_tomcat_server_xml.sh
```

This config creates a script (`files`) and then runs it (`container_command`).  The script checks the `server.xml` for the `UIREncoding="UTF8"` string and if it doesn't find it, it then adds it in using the `sed` command.

The nice thing about this solution is that if you upgrade your version of Tomcat (e.g. from 7 to 8) then you don't have to worry about updating the `server.xml` in your various WAR files.

Also, this example is for adding the `UIREncoding` parameter but the script is very easily adapted to add `<Connector ... />'` property from the original question.

Comment: It really is a smart way to config URIEncoding.

Comment: Can I do this without adding an .ebextensions to my code base? I didn't have one and I have already provisioned the tomcat instance in Beanstalk. I don't want to make any changes to the code itself, if possible.

Comment: Using .ebextensions is the recommended way if you're on ElasticBeanstalk.