# How do I set URIencoding to UTF8 for Tomcat within AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat7, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My application deployed on Tomcat 7 needs to be able to handle non-latin characters properly in get queries properly, to do this I have to add **URIEncoding="UTF-8"** to the **server.xml** file.

```
 <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

then restart Tomcat, and this works.

But how do I do this or equivalent when using **Amazon Web Services** and **Elastic Beanstalk**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to use your own server.xml. You can replace it using ebextensions config files.

Take a look at this question:
[How do I supply configuration to elastic beanstalk tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12264432/161628)

Comment: Great, to clarify I should make a copy of the one currently deployed on EB and edit that, then use ebextensions (which I already do use) as part of my deployement.

Comment: Yes or another option would be to use something like sed to replace the Connector line.