# How to provide a custom log appender to Elastic Beanstalk's Tomcat instance?

Tags: java, tomcat8, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How to drop a custom jar file containing a custom log appender into Tomcat's classpath so that I can reference it in `conf/logging.properties`?

The question below provides some general ideas:

> [How do I supply configuration to elastic beanstalk tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264432/how-do-i-supply-configuration-to-elastic-beanstalk-tomcat)

But I couldn't find any documentation on where Tomcat's classpath is configured, or where a jar could be placed to be automatically picked up.

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful.
[How do I supply configuration to elastic beanstalk tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264432/how-do-i-supply-configuration-to-elastic-beanstalk-tomcat)

The answers contain a method of replacing the entire Tomcat server.xml and to replace only segments of it.
Both updates are part of the WAR file and thus automatically applied on deployment without manual modification to the Elastic Beanstalk application environment.